# Dividing contents with ratios

Tags: ratio

I'm taking a mock test and there is a relatively straight forward question that I am not sure about.

```
Sara and Jenny share some money in the ratio 6:7
Sara gets $96.00

How much does Jenny get?
```

In order to do this question, do I do something like this:

```
6+7 = 13 (total parts)
96 / 6 = 16 (value of each part)
16 * 7 = 112
```

Could anyone check that I am approaching this question correctly please?

Comment: Well done, Jim.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification